# IIS reading web.conf and performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api2

In my code I have dotted around references to pull values from the web.conf file.

```
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]
```

I'm assuming at this point everytime I call this line of code to retrieve entries that my app is physically reading the web.conf file from disk.  Which does raise a potential bottle neck.

But as it's only an assumption I'm hoping I'm wrong, and that IIS loads web.conf into memory so any calls made to access keys are all done in memory.

Is anyone in the know who could confirm?  I just don't want to write code which is going to perform badly :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this Blog entry: http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/web-config-is-cached

The title allready gives you an answer: Web.Config is Cached.

Accessing it shouldn't be your bottle neck.

An more detailed [overview from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178683.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for ASP.Net gives us this:

> At run time, ASP.NET uses the Web.Config files to hierarchically
>   compute a unique collection of configuration settings for each
>   incoming URL request. These settings are calculated only once and then
>   cached on the server.